# Install non-UI app on jailbroken device via AFC2

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am trying to install an app to a jailbroken iPhone from PC via USB (using AFC2), for personal research. The app is actually an installer, so it has no UI.

My biggest 2 problems are: I don't know any API to run a command via an USB services, to run the binary after copying.

Then, I installed a LaunchDaemon plist to start my installer, but it seems that the binary is copied with no execution rights (maybe a limitation in AFC2), so the launch daemon fails.

So now I am stucked. Do you have any ideeas?

UPDATE

Thanks to creker I made some steps into achieving my goal. He provided me with several solutions, but I chosen the automatically install DEB via Cydia, since it looks the most simple and elegant method  of all.

Nevertheless, I hit some bumps with this method also:

- now I am able to succesfully install the .deb file via Cydia; I load the app and a launch daemon in the deb, but the launch daemon is unable to start the app, since installd fails to validate the app, which was fake-signed with ldid (I thought ldid signing is sufficient for running in jailbroken environment); so I guess either I sign it for real or I use a tweak like AppSync, to bypass validation
- I also tried the following formula: a launch daemon to launch a bash script, which then starts the app, since I saw that cydia and OpenSSH registers some launch daemons like that, but my script / launch daemon is ignored, so I presume there should be a trick somewhere. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have a WiFi? If not, you can use USB tunneling. Then you can SCP your app on a device and install it with SSH (give it persmissions you need and then launch). That's enough for testing. Or you can pack it into debian package with postinst script that will do all the installation. Debian packages can be installed manually through ssh and `deb -i` command. Or you can copy it into `/var/root/Media/Cydia/AutoInstall` and it will be installed automatically on device boot.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to install DEB package via Cydia, but after reboot the deb was missing but the app was not copied. The Deb contained the app and a launch daemon for /Library/LaunchDaemons/. Do you know of any restrictions from Cydia, or if there is a log where I could see what happened?

Comment: Don't know of any of that. Try to install in manually to see if your deb is working properly. You can even to it on device itself using MobileTerminal or iFile to install the deb.

Comment: OK finally made it, I guess the control file was missing some content. Now the next question: is it possible to install an app into /Applications this way? since I noticed that, even though in the deb package I put the app into /Applications directory it is actually installed into /private/var/stash/_.sJxnXN/Applications which as far as I know it is sandboxed, but I need it to be in /Applications

Comment: `/Applications` is a symlink that points to `/private/var/stash/_.sJxnXN/Applications` in your case. This is done by Cydia on it's first launch. When it prepares file system it moves any user content that Cydia might install (applications, wallpapers etc) on a bigger partition. By default, it's on the system (firmware) partition which is very small (a couple of hundreds of MB). Cydia moves it to the User Data partition. That path is not sandboxed - sandboxed paths are `/private/var/mobile/Applications` (up to iOS 7) or `/private/var/mobile/Containers` (iOS 8+) where AppStore apps are installed

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made some progress, and updated the question.

Comment: Finally did it, the devil was in the details, I just had to set the root:wheel owner on the files before packing into deb file (I went with the daemon that launches the script that starts the app). @crecker if you like, please add an answer to the question so I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a WiFi? If not, you can use USB tunneling. Then you can SCP your app on a device and install it with SSH (give it persmissions you need and then launch). That's enough for testing. Or you can pack it into debian package with postinst script that will do all the installation. Debian packages can be installed manually through ssh and deb -i command. Or you can copy it into /var/root/Media/Cydia/AutoInstall and it will be installed automatically on device boot.

As for root:wheel, you can do this in your postinst script. The script by default is executed with root permissions. Just set all necessary permissions in it for all your files. If it's a daemon, you can even manually add it to launchd and launch immediatelly.